# Appending to empty list

Tags: python, tkinter

Probably a stupid question, but I am trying to create a an empty list and then append objects to it (in this case a tkinter options menu), but I keep getting a 'KeyError: 0'.

```
size_options= sorted(['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'])
size = "Please choose a size"
quant = "Please choose a quantity"

new_cadet_info = {
"polo": [size, quant],
"ptshort": [size, quant],
"ptshirt": [size, quant],
"top": [size, quant],
"bottom": [size, quant]
}

size_menu = []

for i in range(3):
    size_menu.append(OptionMenu(uniform_frame, new_cadet_info[i][0], *size_options))
    size_menu[i].config(font=("Roboto",17), bg="#1A3B67")
```

What I am trying to achieve is create a menu option for the first 3 items in the 'new_cadet_info' dictionary, and since it is a size menu I want the variable that is being changed to be the first item in the list associated with whatever dictionary key I am currently on. Why am I getting a keyError and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you assuming the KeyError is coming from `.append()`? When chaining methods and getting an unexpected result, it may help to unchain: assign the result of `OptionMenu()` to a variable first, then append that variable. You want to isolate where the KeyError is occuring.

Comment: Please post the traceback which includes the entire error statement and the line that failed.

Comment: `new_cadet_info` is a `dict` which is accessed by keys like "polo" and "ptshort". It doesn't have a numerical index. When you wrote `new_cadet_info[i][0]` what did you want? There are 5 items in the dict, you are looking for 3 things. Its a bit confusing.

Comment: Per tdelaney's comment: try `list(new_cadet_info.items())[i][0]`.